# Find Unmatching Letters between Two Strings

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a query that gives total numbers of unmatched letters between two strings.

For example, I have the given two strings

> String 1: Jamess String 2: Romeeo

I need to find out total number of letters in the second string that don't having a matching in the first string.

The letters would be

> R, o, o and e

(note that the first string has only one e, so the extra e in Romeeo doesn't having a matching in string 1).

In short, Those letters (R, o, o, and e) don't exist in string 1.

Is there away to solve this problem in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amusing puzzle game ;)

Using the analytic function `COUNT()` and by partitioning up to the current row, you are in fact able to "number yours letters":

```
  SELECT letters, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY letters ORDER BY n ROWS 
                        BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt FROM (
    --                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SELECT SUBSTR('Jameess', LEVEL, 1) letters, LEVEL n FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('Jameess')
  )
```

Producing that result:

```
LETTERS CNT
J       1   -- first J
a       1   -- first a
e       1   -- first e
e       2   -- second e
m       1   -- ...
s       1
s       2
```

Do it once for each string, and you only have to compare each letter index it its own group:

```
SELECT s2.letters
FROM (
  SELECT letters,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY letters ORDER BY n ROWS 
                        BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTR('Jameess', LEVEL, 1) letters, LEVEL n FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('Jameess')
  )
) S1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT letters, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY letters ORDER BY n ROWS 
                        BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTR('Romeeeeo', LEVEL, 1) letters, LEVEL n FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('Romeeeeo')
  )
) S2
ON s1.letters = s2.letters AND s1.cnt = s2.cnt
WHERE s1.cnt IS NULL
--    ^^^^^^
-- change to `s2.cnt` to compare your strings the other way around 
-- and replace the RIGHT JOIN by a LEFT JOIN
ORDER BY letters
```

Producing:

```
LETTERS
R
e
e
o
o
```

<sub>(For testing purposes, I add few extra `e` in `Jameess` and `Romeeeeo`)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**In Oracle**,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 'Jamess' str1, 'Romeeo' str2 FROM dual
  3    ),
  4    data2 AS
  5    (SELECT SUBSTR(str1, LEVEL, 1) str1
  6    FROM DATA
  7      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str1)
  8    ),
  9    data3 AS
 10    (SELECT SUBSTR(str2, LEVEL, 1) str2
 11    FROM DATA
 12      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str2)
 13    )
 14  SELECT * FROM data3 WHERE str2 NOT IN
 15    (SELECT str1 FROM data2
 16    )
 17  UNION ALL
 18  SELECT str2
 19  FROM data3
 20  WHERE str2 IN
 21    (SELECT str1 FROM data2
 22    )
 23  GROUP BY str2
 24  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
 25  /

S
-
R
o
o
e

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged with `[plsql]` so I thought a PL/SQL solution would be in order:

```
DECLARE 
  stringA  VARCHAR2(20) := 'Jamess';
  stringB  VARCHAR2(20) := 'Romeeo';
  strDiff  VARCHAR2(20);

  FUNCTION find_unmatched(p1 IN VARCHAR2, p2 IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    s1 VARCHAR2(32767) := p1;
    s2 VARCHAR2(32767) := p2;
    s3 VARCHAR2(32767);
    c   CHAR(1);
    p   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      c := SUBSTR(s2, 1, 1);

      p := INSTR(s1, c);
      IF p = 0 THEN  -- c not found in s1: add to unmatched list and remove from s2
        s3 := s3 || c;
        s2 := SUBSTR(s2, 2);
      ELSE  -- c found in s1: remove from s1 and s2
        s1 := SUBSTR(s1, 1, p-1) || SUBSTR(s1, p+1, LENGTH(s1)-p);
        s2 := SUBSTR(s2, 2);
      END IF;

      IF s1 IS NULL OR s2 IS NULL THEN
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN s3;
  END find_unmatched;

BEGIN
  strDiff := find_unmatched(stringA, stringB);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strDiff=''' || strDiff || '''');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

Try this SQL Query

```
DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(100)='Jamess'
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(100)='Romeeo'
DECLARE @Notmatchstring VARCHAR(100)
SET @Notmatchstring =''
DECLARE @index INT
DECLARE @count INT

SET @count=1
WHILE @count <= LEN(@string2)
BEGIN

    SET @index=CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@string2,@count,1),@string1,0)   

    IF(@index=0)
    BEGIN
    SET @Notmatchstring =@Notmatchstring +' '+SUBSTRING(@string2,@count,1)
    END
    IF(@index>0)
    BEGIN   
    SET @string1=REPLACE(@string1,SUBSTRING(@string2,@count,1),'')
    END
    SET @count=@count+1
END
SELECT @Notmatchstring as NotMatchingCharacter
```

Comment: The question clearly states that the database in use is Oracle, not SQL Server. The [SQL] tag refers to Structured Query Language, not Microsoft's SQL Server product.